# What is the purpose of the election?

Tags: discussion

[2021 Moderator Election - The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/election) says:

- "*election began 3 hours ago*"
- "*in the election phase, up to 10 candidates advance to final community voting.*".

There are only 5 candidates listed for the 10 positions.

It's not at all obvious to me what effect the election will have no matter how I vote.

It's also not obvious to me what the difference is between "election" and "community voting".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had thought the Election page was pretty clear on this - apologies if that isn't the case. This is a standard Stack Exchange election, to elect moderators. We have these any time moderators step down, or we feel we need more moderators as the load increases. Small sites tend to have 3 mods.

This election is partly to bring the number of mods back up to 3 as one stepped down, and partly as up until now, we have been pro-tem mods: this is our first election since graduation so mods need to be elected by the community.

The nomination phase allowed up to 10 candidates to nominate themselves for these 3 positions. We have 5 candidates, so the election is valid. You can see from the top of the election page that we have 5 candidates for 3 positions.

[image]

The community can vote on their 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th choices, and at the close of the election votes will be counted using OpaVote.

The possible effects: As I am the only one of the current mods standing, you will definitely gain 2 new mods. And if 3 others get more votes than I, you may have an entirely new mod team.

Comment: Thanks.  I incorrectly read it as meaning "*We've just begun the election, where up to 10 candidates will be chosen to advance to the final phase of community voting.*".
I saw the "election" and the "final community voting" as two different stages of the process, and couldn't understand what the difference was between them.
Perhaps it was the "up to" that made it look like we still don't know how many will advance, and the purpose of the current stage is to determine that number.
¶ One thing that really *is* missing though is that 3 candidates will be elected.

Comment: Also, is it normal for current mods to have to stand down for reelection? I remember elections in other sites where only the replacements were elected.

Comment: See my 2nd para - this is our first graduation election. There is no standing down. Anyone who wishes to be an elected mod must stand as a candidate - there is no "bye" from pro-tem to elected mod.

Comment: @RayButterworth I have just added in a screenshot of the top of the election page, where it says that this election is for 3 places.